# Search suffix word. Solr 4.5.1

Tags: solr

How do I do a search for the word suffix? I'm using Solr-4.5.1.
Using Solr-3.6.2 I have noted in the schema.xml:
filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"
In solr-4.5.1 does not work.
Thanks.

Comment: EdgeNGramFilterFactory is included in solr 4.5.1. What is not working. Can you be more specific.

Comment: I used a filter class = "solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize = "2" maxGramSize = "50" side = "front" in solr-3.6.2. If I add the schema solr-4.5.1. this filter, the console include:
ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – null:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Side.BACK is not supported anymore as of Lucene 4.4, use ReverseStringFilter up-front and afterward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use the `ReverseStringFilterFactory` like this

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
  ...
```

Comment: please mark your question as solved, by clicking on the check mark beneath my answer, if this solved your question (and you can also upvote my answer ;) )

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Using 2 `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` after each other will cause all the tokens of the first to also be subject to the second, producing more tokens than desired. The solution would be to create two different fields instead, no?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not correct, there is only one result from a fieldType pipeline not two as is implied here.  You will need to copy your source field into a second "backwards" field and also search upon it.